# find $\max$ and $\min$ with Lagrange multipliers. $f(x,y,z)=xyz^2$, $g(x,y,z)=x^2+y^2+z^2-1=0$

Tags: calculus, lagrange-multiplier

Find the $\max$ and the $\min$ with Lagrange multipliers, given  $$f(x,y,z)=xyz^2,$$ $$g(x,y,z)=x^2+y^2+z^2-1=0.$$

[image: My attempt]

Comment: Welcome to MSE. Please use Mathjax when writing equations on this platform :) There is a tutorial on this link: https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference

Comment: In your top branch think about $\lambda=0$, the implications for y and z and what equation 4 has to say about that. Then in the top branch think about $\lambda$ not equal to $0$ and again consider eqn 4. That then leaves you with your bottom branch and you can substitute for $\lambda$ in 1 and 2.

Answer (score 1):

$$F(x,y,z)=(xyz^2)+ \lambda(x^2+y^2+z^2-1)$$
$$F_x=yz^2+2\lambda x$$
$$F_y=xz^2+2\lambda y$$
$$F_z=2xyz+2\lambda z$$
$$F_x,F_y,F_z=0$$
$$2xyz+2\lambda z=0$$
$$\lambda=-xy$$
$$xz^2-2xy^2=0$$
$$yz^2-2x^2y=0$$
$$z^2=2y^2$$
$$z^2=2x^2$$
$$z=\pm y\sqrt{2}$$
$$z=\pm x\sqrt{2}$$
$$y=\frac{\pm z}{\sqrt{2}}$$
$$x=\frac{\pm z}{\sqrt{2}}$$
Therefore, possible combinations of $x,y,z$are:
$$\left(\frac{\pm z}{\sqrt{2}},\frac{\pm z}{\sqrt{2}}, z\right)$$

OR
$$\left(\frac{ z}{\sqrt{2}},\frac{ z}{\sqrt{2}}, z\right),\left(\frac{ -z}{\sqrt{2}},\frac{ z}{\sqrt{2}}, z\right),\left(\frac{ z}{\sqrt{2}},\frac{ -z}{\sqrt{2}}, z\right),\left(\frac{- z}{\sqrt{2}},\frac{- z}{\sqrt{2}}, z\right)$$

Also, $$x^2+y^2+z^2=1$$
$$\frac{z^2}{2}+\frac{z^2}{2}+z^2=1$$
$$z^2=\frac{1}{2}$$
$$z=\frac{\pm 1}{\sqrt{2}}$$

Therefore, all possible values of $(x,y,z)$ are:
$$\left(\frac{ 1}{{2}},\frac{ 1}{{2}}, \frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}\right),\left(\frac{ -1}{{2}},\frac{ 1}{{2}}, \frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}\right),\left(\frac{ 1}{{2}},\frac{ -1}{{2}}, \frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}\right),\left(\frac{ -1}{{2}},\frac{ -1}{{2}}, \frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}\right)$$
$$\left(\frac{ 1}{{2}},\frac{ 1}{{2}}, \frac{-1}{\sqrt{2}}\right),\left(\frac{ -1}{{2}},\frac{ 1}{{2}}, \frac{-1}{\sqrt{2}}\right),\left(\frac{ 1}{{2}},\frac{ -1}{{2}}, \frac{-1}{\sqrt{2}}\right),\left(\frac{ -1}{{2}},\frac{ -1}{{2}}, \frac{-1}{\sqrt{2}}\right)$$

The minimum possible value of $$xyz^2=\left(\frac{-1}{2}\right)\left(\frac{1}{2}\right)\left(\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}\right)^2=\frac{-1}{8}$$

Answer (score 1):

Using the technique of Lagrange multiplier is a very standard technique for such  a  problem. I would like to solve the problem as the following:

Note that $(x, y,z)$ lies on the unit sphere. Simply use the spherical coordinates, and then you have  $$ f= \frac{1}{8} \sin (2 \theta) \sin ^2(2 \phi)$$. This gives us min and max of f.